# How should I find the nontrivial solution of this Bernoulli equation? Can anyone please check my work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Find the nontrivial solution of the differential equation $x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x^4y^2, y(1)=1.$

Here's my work:

Note that the Bernoulli equation has the form: $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n$ where $n\neq 0, 1.$

Consider the differential equation $x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x^4y^2, y(1)=1.$

Then we have $\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x}=x^3y^2,$ where $P(x)=\frac{1}{x}, Q(x)=x^3, n=2.$

This implies that $u=y^{1-n}=y^{-1}, y=\frac{1}{u}, \frac{dy}{dx}=-u^{-2}\frac{du}{dx}.$

After substutiting $y$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$, we get $-u^{-2}\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{1}{xu}=\frac{x^3}{u^2}.$

Multiplying all terms by $-u^2,$ we get $\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{u}{x}=-x^3.$

Observe that $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u}{x}-x^3$

$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}(u-x^4)$

$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u-x^4}{x}$

$du=\frac{u-x^4}{x}dx$

$\frac{du}{u-x^4}=\frac{dx}{x}$

Now I'm stuck. I know that the integral of $\frac{dx}{x}$ should be $ln(x)$ but I don't know how to take the integral of the left hand side, $\frac{du}{u-x^4}$. What should I do from here?

Comment: When you get $\dfrac{du}{dx}-\dfrac{u}{x}=-x^3$, note that it is a linear differential equation. So try to solve using integrating factor.

Comment: So the integrating factor is $C/x?$ What to do from here then?

Comment: You can simply take $C=1$, to get the integrating factor to be $\dfrac1x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution:
\begin{align}
x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x^4y^2 &\implies \frac{d}{dx}(xy)=x^2(xy)^2 \\
&\implies \int\frac{d(xy)}{(xy)^2}=\int x^2dx \\
&\implies -\frac{1}{xy}=\frac{x^3}{3}+C \\
&\implies y=-\frac{1}{\frac{x^4}{3}+Cx}. \tag{1}
\end{align}
The integration constant $C$ is fixed by the condition $y(1)=1$:
$$
1=-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{3}+C} \implies C=-\frac{4}{3}. \tag{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
y=-\frac{1}{\frac{x^4}{3}-\frac{4x}{3}}=\frac{3}{4x-x^4}. \tag{3}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really like this alternative solution, it was very effective and easier to follow, yet the solution was totally correct.

Answer (score 1):

You already have:
$$
\tag{$*$}
u' = \frac 1x\cdot u - x^3\ , \qquad u(1) = 1\ .
$$
The solution for the associated equation $u'=\frac 1x u$, i.e. $u'/u=1/x$, i.e. $(\log u)' = (\log x)'$, i.e. $\log u=\log x+K$  is of the general shape $u=Cx$. We are searching a solution for $(*)$ of the shape:
$$
u(x)=C(x)\cdot x\ .
$$
We plug in into $(*)$ and obtain successively:
$$
\begin{aligned}
C'(x)\cdot x+C(x) &=C(x)-x^3\ ,\\
C'(x)\cdot x &=-x^3\ ,\\
C'(x) &=-x^2\ ,\\
C(x) &=-\frac 13x^3 + c\ .&&\text{ And from $C(1)=u(1)=1$ we get:}\\[2mm]
C(x)&=\frac 13(4-x^3)\ .&&\text{ We obtain $u$ and $y$:}\\
u(x) &=\frac 13(4x-x^4)\ ,\\
y(x)&=\frac 3{4x-x^4}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Computer check, here sage:

```
x = var('x')
y = function('y')(x)
desolve( x*diff(y, x) +y - x^4*y^2 == 0, y, ics = [1, 1] )
```

gives:

```
-3/(x^4 - 4*x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.